# Use Images for matplotlib axis labels?

Tags: python, image, graph, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'd like to use images instead of strings as the axis labels for a bar chart plot in matplotlib. Is there an analogous function to do something like that to the label function below?

```python
ax1.set_xticklabels(('< 1 wk', '1-2 wks', '>2 wks ago'))
```

Comment: Thanks Yann - that does answer my question, but what's the syntax of adding it to the y-axis rather than x?

Comment: The last bit of that answer focuses on using images as tick marks. You are placing the images outside of the axes. In that example, I set the x position of the images at varying x tick mark values, and I set the y value to some constant (`TICKYPOS = -.6`) that was negative so that it would be below the x axis. You want to do the opposite for the y axis. You want a constant x that is negative and varying y values. The magnitude of these values will depend on the units of your axes, because the positions are defined in data units.

Comment: @Yann: I would say you'd answered the question. Perhaps you should turn it into an answer rather than a comment?